the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
The ranked_collective pallet has been updated to include AddOrigin and RemoveOrigin, my intention it to update the various collectives in the kusama and Polkadot runtimes to include these but I keep encountering this error.
the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`



Some of your dependencies are coming from github and some are defined local. You need to check your cargo.toml for the same

How do you mean?
